# upload file from adding a custom step on checkout onepage

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, ajax, file-upload

I have created a new step after payment on checkout onepage and form in this step contains a file type element. I have to upload a file and save file using Ajax. I'm using the `formData` object in my js file to get the file details in `$_FILES` array in php but it's not working. Doing simply like this in my js file.

[image: checkout onepage]

```
save: function () {
        //verifyStep = document.getElementById('verify-step').value;
        var formElement = document.getElementById("co-verify-form");
        var formData = new FormData(formElement);
        console.log(formElement);

        if (checkout.loadWaiting != false)
            return;
        if (this.validate()) {

            checkout.setLoadWaiting('verify');
            var request = new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveUrl,
                {
                    method: 'post',
                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                    onSuccess: this.onSave,
                    onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                    parameters: formData,
                }
            );
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by using `xmlHttpRequest` object by putting it on some condition because in Age verification step there are 3 substeps and on third step, there is a file upload option I used. So i just put it only under step 3. but didn't find any solution to get content of file element of form using `formData` with magento's default `prototype.js`. Following is the code.

```
if (this.validate()) {
    if (verifyStep.value == '3') {
        var formElement = document.getElementById("co-verify-form");
        var formData = new FormData(formElement);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                alert('File uploaded Successfully');
            }
        };
        request.open("POST", this.uploadUrl, true);
        request.send(formData);
    }

    checkout.setLoadWaiting('verify');
    var request = new Ajax.Request(
        this.saveUrl,
        {
            method: 'post',
            onComplete: this.onComplete,
            onSuccess: this.onSave,
            onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
            parameters: Form.serialize(this.form),
            //postBody: formData
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I am following this method, Then how could I retrieve the file type attribute in contoller?

Answer (score 0):

This one also worked for me:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('filename', jQuery('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.uploadUrl,
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```